# Vaadin Calendar with EvenProvider doesnt refresh data on change

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using Vaadin Calendar component with EventProvider. It loads items corrently when displayed inititaly, but when I edit the calendar item it doest reflect changes on the screen. (caption name change or date changes) I even tried to set provider once again after entry update  `cal.setEventProvider(p)`; but it doesnt force calendar to fetch fresh data from provider. Any hint how to work with EventProvider and do entries updates on calendar?

Comment: You may want to share some code?

Comment: Please share the code. its difficult to figure out by looking just at explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem a while back (Vaadin 7.1), and found out that the [default implementation of ContainerEventProvider](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/ui/components/calendar/ContainerEventProvider.java) doesn't work properly. I do not remember all the details but my investigation showed a problem with the `getEvents` method. To solve it, I subclassed ContainerEventProvider with my own class and implemented an override of `getEvents`:

```
@Override
public List<CalendarEvent> getEvents(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    eventCache.clear();

    // int[] rangeIndexes = getFirstAndLastEventIndex(startDate, endDate);
    for (int i = 0; i < container.size(); i++) {
        eventCache.add(getEvent(i));
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(eventCache);
}
```

And this is the function that assigns a container to the calendar:

```
public void setCalendarContainerDataSource(Indexed ds) {
    // this.vaadinCal.setContainerDataSource(ds); // this did't work
    MyCalendarContainerEventProvider provider = new MyCalendarContainerEventProvider(ds);
    provider.addEventSetChangeListener(new CalendarEventProvider.EventSetChangeListener() {

        public void eventSetChange(EventSetChangeEvent changeEvent) {
            vaadinCal.markAsDirty();
        }
    });
    provider.addEventChangeListener(new EventChangeListener() {

        public void eventChange(EventChangeEvent changeEvent) {
            // Repaint if event changes
            vaadinCal.markAsDirty();
        }
    });
    vaadinCal.setEventProvider(provider);
}
```